# using linq to xml in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-xml

I did implement a web application(asp.net,c#) where it has couple of pages .Each page has the ability to read the values from an xml file and passes into couple of text boxes in each page.User has the ability to edit the values and save,which inturn saves the xml file.I did use the linq to xml .

I have to move to the silverlight now.so i am trying to implement the same logic in a new silverlight project.I m trying to use the linq to xml in silverlight also.But some how i am unable to read the xml file which is not in the xap file.Here is my code

```
 XDocument doc = Document.Load("C:\Data\Data.exe.config");
            var applicationSettings = (from x in doc.Descendants("applicationSettings")
                                       from kvpair in .Element("Data.Properties.Settings").Elements("setting")
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           Name = kvpair.Attribute("name").Value,
                                           Node = kvpair.Element("value")
                                       }).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, y => y);

            string Account  = applicationSettings["Account no"].Node.Value.ToString();
           txtAccountno.Text = AttendanceWindow;
            string Details=applicationSettings["Details"].Node.Value.ToString();
            txtDetails.Text = Details;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that "C:\Data\Data.exe.config" is a file that sits on the server? Keep in mind that Silverlight is executing on the client-side. Not only would you have to give Silverlight permission to access that directory [(see this link for some details)](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/204361.aspx), but you'd be accessing the client's hard disk, not the server's. In order to get that file's contents, you'd be better off parsing the XML server-side and sending whatever settings you require from it to Silverlight via web services.

If the file really does sit on the client's computer, then you need to create an out-of-browser Silverlight project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721082(VS.95).aspx

**EDIT:**

Ah, I think I see what's going on now. The Document.Load method by default assumes the URI points to a resource within the XAP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538371(v=vs.95).aspx

What you'll probably need to do is described in this MSDN article, which will use a stream approach to loading the XML: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645034(v=vs.95).aspx#Y0

Comment: avanek:yes the file sits on the server.And my silverlight application also sits on the server and its has access to the file to read and write.

Comment: Is the code throwing an exception then? Any additional information you could provide would be appreciated.

Comment: Exception:Cannot open 'file:/C:/Data/Data.exe.config'. The Uri parameter must be a relative path pointing to content inside the Silverlight application's XAP package. If you need to load content from an arbitrary Uri, please see the documentation on Loading XML content using WebClient/HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is related to which areas on the disk you are allowed to access.

You need ensure that Silverlight can access the file, that it has rights to the files location, and that silverlight is configured to be able to access local files. Either the file must be moved to local storage or you must run with elevated privilages out of the browser.

See also: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/FileExplorerInSilverlight.aspx for an example of accessing files from Silverlight

Comment: :Probably you are thinking the other way..i am not supposed to move the file.The xml file i am trying to load is always in the same location.

Comment: I was thinking of moving the file to local storage. I have updated the answer to make it more clear

Comment: exception:Cannot open 'file:///C:/SITA/PaxServices/FidsValidationHost.exe.config'. The Uri parameter must be a relative path pointing to content inside the Silverlight application's XAP package. If you need to load content from an arbitrary Uri, please see the documentation on Loading XML content using WebClient/HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 5 it is possible to run the Silverlight application in-browser with elevated permissions, enabling you to access the entire file system. Otherwise you are restricted to the isolated storage area.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the XML file as a resource file in the XAP? In that case you could use Application.GetResourceStream(Uri) to get a stream info object to the XML file, and then you could use XDocument.Load(Stream) to load the stream into an XDocument.

Comment: Nope i am not supposed to move the file from the location on the server...i am looking on the lines of the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645034(v=vs.95).aspx#Y0